# ClojureScript advanced compilation of pre and post conditions

Tags: clojurescript, google-closure-compiler

I have the following piece of code in a ClojureScript project :

```
(ns project.lib
  (:require [cljs.test :refer-macros [is]]))

(defn my-fn [p]
  {:pre  [(is (#{:allowed-key :another-allowed-key} p))]}
  ;;...
  )
```

I would like to know if I can control the behaviour of the `:pre` and `:post` assertions, and generally what is the way to make sure that some code related to parameter checking is not included.

**Note** : I am aware of the `:closure-define` compiler option, but not sure how to apply it to this specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the compiler option `:elide-asserts` to `true` to eliminate all assertions, including `:pre` and `:post` assertions.

This flag is independent of `:advanced` and needs to be set even under that mode to eliminate the assertions from production code.

See https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Compiler-Options#elide-asserts

Also note that, generally, the `cljs.test` namespace would only be used in unit test namespaces, which would be placed in a separate directory (perhaps under `"test"` as opposed to to `"src"`) and, if using `lein`, you would use `:source-paths` so as to not include the tests in your production builds.

Having said that, using `:pre` and `:post` is perfectly fine in production code—just use "regular" predicates instead of the `cljs.test` `is` macro. For your specific example, `is` could be eliminated as the precondition simply needs to evaluate to something truthy.